# Should I archive unused data?

Tags: mysql, transactions

I have a table in the database that accepts maybe x00 inserts every minute, so it will get large very quickly.

Should I archive this data on a regular basis, and what's the best way to do it?

I'm currently doing something like this with a transaction:

```
function doArchiveMyTable() {
    $transaction->query("
        INSERT INTO `archive_my_table`
        SELECT * FROM `my_table`
        WHERE ...
    ");

    $transaction->query("
        DELETE FROM `my_table`
        WHERE ...
    ");

    return $transaction->commit();
}
```

Should I even bother at all? It would be VERY bad if I lost data, but it would also be VERY bad if the database was slow.

**Extra Info About Use:**

The database is used by an API which is used by end users of a game. The database is used to store various score data which updates often.

It's not actually live yet, so I would estimate 200 users at any time and all performing around 10 inserts a minute.

The users and other users can query the API to find data about other users, and the backend scripts also query this data often.

All queries are either SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE and occasionally DELETE.

Users query the database around 15 times per minute, but all of these calls are made in a short period of 20 seconds.

Comment: How is the read part of the system set up?  how many users, what kind of querying do you need to do and how often?

Comment: Have you tried inserting a few million rows (~a day worth of data) to see how the system behaves?